# How to create many to many relationship between models in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following models and serializers:

#### Models:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SiteCategory(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

#### Serializers:

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta  :
        model = Site
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'created', 'categories')

class SiteCategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteCategory
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'created', 'sites')
```

I want to setup a many-to-many relationship between the sites and categories so for e.g.:

`Site1` categories: `Category1`, `Category2`.
`Site2` categories: `Category2`, `Category3`.
`Category1` sites: `Site1`.
`Category2` sites: `Site1`, `Site2`.
`Category3` sites: `Site2`.

I'm kinda clueless on how should I set up my models and serializers to achive the output described about.

Answer (score 0):

Fist, your site's model should contain a category item as many-to-many field:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(SiteCategory)
```

Comment: Yeah but `SiteCategory` is declared after `Site` so it would throw an error, right? By the way, let's assume I've created the `category` field, then how to progress further?

Comment: @Szabolcs you can use quoted name of the model that is not defined yet `category = models.ManyToManyField('SiteCategory')`. See [ManyToManyField spec](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) and [Examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: @akarilimano I'll try that, thank you. Other suggestions for the question?

Answer (score 0):

To nest serializers you just use them as any other field

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    categories = SiteCategorySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        depth = 1
        model = Site
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'created', 'categories')
```

For nesting in both directions use the `depth = 1` in the Meta class

Comment: And how to define `sites` in the `SiteCategorySerializer` object? Also can you explain how to construct the models (`Site`, `SiteCategory`) with the same constraints?